# Open to many files without closing cursor, freezes if I close the cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting the error:

> Caused By: Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available
>   file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.

Happens on line 56 of my bottom fragment. I have tried `db.close();` To close the DB after the adapter has been populated. Not sure why I am getting this after closing the DB. If I try to close the DB and cursor after using them I get error to attempt to re-open an already-closed object. So its mad if I don't close them because it's to much, then mad if I close them and won't let me re-open them.

```
public class BottomFragment extends Fragment {
    public Cursor mBottomCursor, mNewBottomCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private ListView mBottomListView;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private String table = EmployeeDBHandler.TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
    int mStartingEmployeeID = myStartingNumber;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_list, container, false);
        dbHandler = EmployeeDBHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mBottomCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +
                "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " ORDER BY " +
                "Last_name" + " ASC", null);
        mBottomListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        BottomListCursorAdapter mBottomAdapter = new BottomListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mBottomCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(mBottomAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshList(Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
        dbHandler = EmployeeDBHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mNewBottomCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +
                "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mEmployeeNumber + " ORDER BY " +
                "Last_name" + " ASC", null);
        BottomListCursorAdapter bottomListCursorAdapter = new BottomListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
        bottomListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(mNewBottomCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomListCursorAdapter); //this is where Logcat says the error is occurring 
        db.close();
    }
}
```

I have also tried to close the cursor by

```
public void refreshList(Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
        dbHandler = EmployeeDBHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            mNewBottomCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                    "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +
                    "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mEmployeeNumber + " ORDER BY " +
                    "Last_name" + " ASC", null);
            BottomListCursorAdapter bottomListCursorAdapter = new BottomListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), mNewBottomCursor);
            bottomListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(mNewBottomCursor);
            mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomListCursorAdapter);
        } finally {
            mNewBottomCursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

I do this for the refreshList method the application just freezes when this method is called. If I remove this and do the first refreshList method shown, I get the too many files opened.

Answer (score 0):

You should create one SQLiteDatabase handler in the whole app (Singleton). you should close it in onStop. You are closing the database, however you might forget to call the refreshList ( just a guess)

Comment: I do have a DBhandler singleton class. I just not sure how to place my rawQuerys into it right now as methods as they are Where clauses. I even have the synchronized method for getInstance across the whole app. So db.close in onStop inside the Fragment?

Comment: I think your post belongs to the comment section.